# problem with haml I study Ruby on rails stumbled where with the following

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

NameError in Posts#index
Showing /home/alexandr/Huntjob/app/views/posts/index.html.haml where line #4 raised:

undefined local variable or method `haml_temp' for #<#:0x00005621a21d4538>
Did you mean?  haml_tag
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRvl7.png)

**Code where an error occurs**

```
- @posts.each do |post|
=link_to (image_tag post.image.url(:small))
%h2= link_to post.title, post
= link_to "Add New Inspiration", new_post_path
```

**Post controller**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

def index
@posts = Post.all.order("created_at")

end

def show

end

def new
@post = current_user.posts.build
end

def create
@post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)

if @post.save
  redirect_to @post
else
  render 'new'
end
end

def edit
end

def update
if @post.update(post_params)
  redirect_to @post
else
  render 'edit'
end
end

def destroy
 @post.destroy
 redirect_to root_path

 end

 private

 def find_post
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def post_params

  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :link, :description, :image)
  end


   end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HAML is indentation sensitive. From the screenshot I see that the problem is in indentations.

That should work:

```
- @posts.each do |post|
  = link_to(image_tag post.image.url(:small))
  %h2= link_to post.title, post
= link_to "Add New Inspiration", new_post_path
```

Make sure you have two spaces before line 2 and 3.

Comment: Ouuu Yeee, Thanks I realized that it was indented, but I tried various options, but your worker, thanks a lot, Apparently I'm too dumb :)